# How can I rename a PDF file while viewing it?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, rename

I have many PDF files that I need to rename based on their visual content. Is there a PDF file viewer that will allow me to rename the file from within the viewer without having to go back to the file manager / command line?

I'm not looking for a "Save As" feature as that will result in an additional deletion step.

This functionality is available in tools like nomacs and geeqie but unfortunately they don't support PDF files.

Comment: If you launch the PDF from the file manager, it would be relatively easy to use Alt+Tab to switch back to the file manager, and press F2 to rename it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Zathura](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/) can run external commands, so you can rename files using it. Open a file, then in Zathura, do:

```
:exec mv % foo.pdf
```

(The syntax is somewhat like Vim - `:` to start command mode, `%` stands for the filename, but that's about it.) But it doesn't pick up that the open file has been moved, so you're left with a blank window after moving. You can open the new PDF file likewise:

```
:open bar.pdf
```

It's available for installation in the official repos:

```
sudo apt install zathura
```